# animated sliding element with

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation

Quick question. I've got some jquery script I'm trying to get working. What I'm trying to do is slide animated div from top, then slide it back after some delay.

```
(function animate() {
    var block = $('#allpage');
    block.slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500).animate({backgroundColor: $.Color(block.css('backgroundColor')).hue('+=3')}, 5, animate);
})();
```

I've found the code of background color animation elsewhere and tried to add sliding but it doesn't slide back or just slides continuously and doesn't stop. Interesting part about this code:

```
.animate({backgroundColor: $.Color(block.css('backgroundColor')).hue('+=3')}, 5, animate)
```

Is that it works only with 1.6.4 version of jquery. Maybe there are some modern ways of animating the background the same way?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to break up the function calls e.g.
block.slideDown(500);
block.delay(2000);
...
?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!